# jquery location.pathname.split("/") returning empty first and last elements

Tags: jquery, arrays

I am using `var url = location.pathname.split("/")` to part split a url.

The first and last elements of the resulting are always empty. Can anyone explain why this would be?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because path starts with an / and there is an empty string before this. 
If path also ends with / there will also be another empty string behind.

This has nothing to do with jQuery, its plain JavaScript behaviour.
If you want to get rid, you could remove the '/' char at the start/end of location.pathname or just ignore empty strings in your array.

Answer (score 1):

Well, consider the following url `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18762585/jquery-location-pathname-split-returning-empty-first-and-last-elements/`. Path name is `/questions/18762585/jquery-location-pathname-split-returning-empty-first-and-last-elements/` and there is nothing before the first "/" and after the last "/".

```
["", "questions", "18762585", 
 "jquery-location-pathname-split-returning-empty-first-and-last-elements", 
 "18762683", ""]
```

Answer (score 1):

If string starts with your split delimitr, first element is empty, because there is nothing before `/`. The same thing with the last `/` in the string - if there is nothing after, it gives you empty element in your result array.

Examples:

```
'/foo/bar/'.split('/')    // ["", "foo", "bar", ""]
'foo/bar/'.split('/')     // ["foo", "bar", ""]
'foo/bar'.split('/')      // ["foo", "bar"]
```

Answer (score 1):

location.pathname returns the pathname part of the URL. In other words, it returns the path without the host and without the query string.

i.e, the pathname for "http://www.stackoverflow.com/question/1/50/hello?answers=yes" is "/question/1/50/hello".

So, you're probably question on a URL that looks like "http://site.com/a/b/c/", which gives the pathname "/a/b/c/". Splitting on that by "/", will return strings seperated by "/". There is nothing before the first and last ones, so you will get empty string for the first and last token.

Answer (score 1):

This might be clear if your test printing your pathname. It usually starts with a '/'. And if there is nothing in the end after the last '/' then you would get such a result.